# add unique object based on a its key in embedded document of mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to add only unique object based on 1 key ie 'variableName' inside an embedded document ie 'variables' in our case. I am using mongoose api to do so in nodejs.

A document sample :

```
{
  "botname": "bot1",
  "variables": [
    {
      "variableName": "variable1",
      "variableValue": "value"
    },
    {
      "variableName": "variable2",
      "variableValue": "value"
    },
    {
      "variableName": "variable3",
      "variableValue": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here in below code, "botname" field finds a specific document from db and inside that document I am trying to add an object based on unique variableName. I wish not to have 2 objects with same variableName.

Now when I am trying to add a new object inside above array, duplication occurs. I tried $addOnSet as well but didnt work.

```
findOneAndUpdate({ "botname": req.params.botName },
      { $push: { variables: {"variableName" : req.body.variableName, "value": req.body.value}} });
```

Comment: You can add an additional condition to the filter, that `variableName` with value `req.body.variableName` is not in the array already.

Comment: yeah I could do that, It would solve the problem of adding duplicate but then how would I be able to show restriction in response about 'variableName already exists'

Comment: The update would have modified zero documents (the update result has this info). You have translate it into a response message.

Comment: Okay I will try that. before that can you please also help with the conditional statement you are speaking of. I am quite beginner to nodejs and mongoose so I am asking.

Comment: There are lot of examples at [Query an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/index.html). Also, see the `$not` logical operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As prasad_ mentioned in the comments, you might consider using an additional filter.

To achieve the outcome you want, adjust the query by making sure that it doesn't include the variableName value you're looking for. Adding `"variables.variableName": { $ne: "variable1"` to your query is one way to achieve that.

```
> db.test.findAndModify({query: {"botname":"bot1", "variables.variableName": { $ne: "variable1" }}, update: {$push: { variables: { variableName: "variable1", variableValue: "BADDDD"}}}})
< ERROR: No document was found matching the query and sort. When sorting, all attributes need to be present in the document.
```

When I try with a valid value, it works!

```
> db.test.findAndModify({query: {"botname":"bot1", "variables.variableName": { $ne: "variable4" }}, update: {$push: { variables: { variableName: "variable4", variableValue: "Gooood"}}}})
Operation consumed 15.76 RUs
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eb093cc7791b6157023b066"),
    "botname" : "bot1",
    "variables" : [
        {
            "variableName" : "variable1",
            "variableValue" : "value"
        },
        {
            "variableName" : "variable2",
            "variableValue" : "value"
        },
        {
            "variableName" : "variable3",
            "variableValue" : "value"
        }
    ]
}
> db.test.find({})
Operation consumed 2.28 RUs
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eb093cc7791b6157023b066"),
    "botname" : "bot1",
    "variables" : [
        {
            "variableName" : "variable1",
            "variableValue" : "value"
        },
        {
            "variableName" : "variable2",
            "variableValue" : "value"
        },
        {
            "variableName" : "variable3",
            "variableValue" : "value"
        },
        {
            "variableName" : "variable4",
            "variableValue" : "Gooood"
        }
    ]
}
```

Be sure that you have an index on `botname` to avoid a scan.